# client denied by server configuration: /web/.env

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

At my Laravel backend, i found that .env file was publicly accessible !

So i fixted it at htaccess like this:

```js
Options -Indexes

<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

now i'm getting those errors at my log :

/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mysite.com/error.log

```js
[Sat Jul 24 02:30:02.012555 2021] [access_compat:error] [pid 12573] [client 34.68.38.253:57077] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/.env
 
[Sat Jul 24 02:41:45.397639 2021] [access_compat:error] [pid 12573] [client 77.247.127.218:51261] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/.env
 
[Sat Jul 24 04:01:06.465017 2021] [access_compat:error] [pid 10206] [client 162.55.61.168:35064] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/.env 

[Sat Jul 24 05:13:38.355428 2021] [access_compat:error] [pid 32043] [client 27.255.90.119:16470] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/.env 

[Sat Jul 24 10:56:19.576281 2021] [access_compat:error] [pid 15892] [client 45.87.61.234:50726] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/.env
```

What's the reason ? do i have to worry about ? how to fix it ?

Config: VPS Debian 9, apache 2.4.25, ispconfig, Laravel 5.3.31

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is because by default apache will have this security feature turned on

```
Require all denied
```

You can disable that by adding this in the config file of apache:

```
Require all granted
```